# How to compile XBMC from source code

Tags: linux, git, xbmc, kodi

I want to compile XBMC from source code and i have an error about dependecies.This are the steps i follow :

```
1. `$git clone git://github.com/xbmc/xbmc.git`
2. `$cd $HOME/xbmc`
3. `$./bootstrap`
4. `$./configure`

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for git... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... none
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... none
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... none
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... none
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features by default... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=gnu++11... no
checking whether g++ supports C++11 features with -std=gnu++0x... yes
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for uid_t in sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for working chown... yes
checking for dirent.h that defines DIR... yes
checking for library containing opendir... none required
checking whether closedir returns void... no
checking for error_at_line... yes
checking for _LARGEFILE_SOURCE value needed for large files... no
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking whether lstat correctly handles trailing slash... yes
checking whether lstat accepts an empty string... no
checking whether lstat correctly handles trailing slash... (cached) yes
checking for working memcmp... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for utime.h... yes
checking for alarm... yes
checking for working mktime... yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for working mmap... yes
checking sys/select.h usability... yes
checking sys/select.h presence... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking sys/socket.h usability... yes
checking sys/socket.h presence... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking types of arguments for select... int,fd_set *,struct timeval *
checking return type of signal handlers... void
checking whether stat accepts an empty string... no
checking for working strcoll... yes
checking for strftime... yes
checking for working strtod... yes
checking whether utime accepts a null argument... yes
checking for vprintf... yes
checking for _doprnt... no
checking for atexit... yes
checking for dup2... yes
checking for fdatasync... yes
checking for floor... no
checking for fs_stat_dev... no
checking for ftime... yes
checking for ftruncate... yes
checking for getcwd... yes
checking for gethostbyaddr... yes
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for getpagesize... (cached) yes
checking for getpass... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for inet_ntoa... yes
checking for lchown... yes
checking for localeconv... yes
checking for memchr... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for memset... yes
checking for mkdir... yes
checking for modf... yes
checking for munmap... yes
checking for pow... no
checking for rmdir... yes
checking for select... yes
checking for setenv... yes
checking for setlocale... yes
checking for socket... yes
checking for sqrt... no
checking for strcasecmp... yes
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strcspn... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strerror... yes
checking for strncasecmp... yes
checking for strpbrk... yes
checking for strrchr... yes
checking for strspn... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for strtol... yes
checking for strtoul... yes
checking for sysinfo... yes
checking for tzset... yes
checking for utime... yes
checking for posix_fadvise... yes
checking for localtime_r... yes
checking size of int... 4
checking size of size_t... 8
checking for __sync_add_and_fetch(temp, 1)... yes
checking for __sync_sub_and_fetch(temp, 1)... yes
checking for __sync_val_compare_and_swap(temp, 1, 1)... yes
checking for std::u16string... yes
checking for std::u32string... yes
checking for char16_t... yes
checking for char32_t... yes
checking size of wchar_t... 4
checking sys/inotify.h usability... yes
checking sys/inotify.h presence... yes
checking for sys/inotify.h... yes
checking boost/circular_buffer.hpp usability... no
checking boost/circular_buffer.hpp presence... no
checking for boost/c

ircular_buffer.hpp... no
    configure: error: Could not find a required library. Please see the README for your platform.

5. `$make`
6. `$sudo make install`
```

./configure should create a Makefile to be executed by the next command "make" but it didn't create it.

Comment: You are missing a required library to install XBMC (btw. really XMBC? Not kodi?) as stated. Did you have a look at the requirements according to the readme and installed all of them on your system? Otherwise, please provide the complete output of the `configure` call.

Comment: @languitar updated.

Comment: From the log I would guess that boost is missing, usually a package named `{lib,}boost.*{-dev}`

Comment: Tried `make dependencies` before `make`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your trying to do. If your using a newish version of the code, then you should be using cmake and be following this readme https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/tree/master/cmake#linux.  That points here for Linux:  https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/blob/master/docs/README.linux

Specifically, for Linux you create a subdirectory `kodi-build` under the git workspace and create the build environment there.  Building out-of-tree is preferable, but addons will want the built tree in that location, so follow their instructions on this.

From the aforementioned README.linux:

```
Create and change to build directory 
    $ mkdir kodi-build && cd kodi-build
    $ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
    $ cmake --build . -- VERBOSE=1
```

You may find missing dependencies when you attempt to run either of these cmake commands (there are a LOT of dependencies).  You can then use your distribution's package management system to find the packages needed for the fulfillment (such as `dnf provides */<name>` on Fedora).